# Toolkit not beeping on ubuntu

Tags: java, toolkit, beep

I am having problems with Toolkit's beep.  I commented out the two speaker disabling lines in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`.  I cannot use the console code `7` to beep because I need it to work in Swing and I would like it to be audible in Eclipse IDE (rather than to show a special symbol in the console-like pane in Eclipse).  When not in the Eclipse IDE, I have tested code `7` and found it to be audible so I know it is not a loose connector problem.  I do have nice sound effects via .wav files but sometimes I just want a simple beep and I don't want to use a lot of CPU cycles to achieve it.  Presently I am using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("beep")` but that also seems a bit excessive.   I am on ubuntu 10.10.  The computer board is a Gigabyte MA 770 UD3. Below is the offending program.

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;

public class Beeper
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
    }
}
```

From blacklist.conf is the following.

```
# low-quality, just noise when being used for sound playback, causes
# hangs at desktop session start (Ubuntu: #246969)
#blacklist snd_pcsp

# ugly and loud noise, getting on everyone's nerves; this should be done by a
# nice pulseaudio bing (Ubuntu: #77010)
#blacklist pcspkr
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your `pcspks` module isn't loaded... I had the same problem and found out that on my system (14.04 LTS), it wasn't.

Check if it's loaded by doing a `lsmod | grep pcspkr` in a terminal. If you get a line similar to

```
pcspkr                 12718  0 `
```

it is loaded. If you do not get any output back from the command, try to load the module:

```
sudo modprobe pcspkr
```

That did the trick for me.

Comment: If you want to remove it, run `sudo modprobe -r pcspkr`